# Vue.js fetch returns empty responseText

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api

I am trying to make my first vue.js app work. At least I am able to do 'fetch' with result 200 (that is a some kind of success) with the following code:

```
    fetch("validate-recaptcha.php", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

        //make sure to serialize your JSON body
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: "myName",
            password: "myPassword"
        })
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //do something awesome that makes the world a better place
        if (response.status == 200) {
            alert(response.statusText + " " + response.responseText);
        }
        else {
            alert("Error: " + response.statusText);
        }
    });
```

but it is not clear why response.responseText in undefined. If I open [the URL I query](https://test.developernote.com/JsLib/contact-form/validate-recaptcha.php) in a browser I get this:

```
{"secret":"yoursecretkey","remoteip":"97.33.22.522"}
```

so at least the content is not empty, but the JavaScript shows the message "OK undefined".

Links:

1. [Full source](https://github.com/elephantbug/JsLib/tree/master/contact-form) code.
2. [Live demo](https://test.developernote.com/JsLib/contact-form/) (press Send Form button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) resulting from `fetch()` does not have a `responseText` property, hence the `undefined`. You can extract the JSON data from the response using method `json()` on the the response. [responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) exists with `XMLHttpRequest`, but not with `fetch()`:

```
fetch("validate-recaptcha.php", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name: "myName", password: "myPassword" })
})
.then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 200) {
        alert(response.statusText);
    }
    else {
        alert("Error: " + response.statusText);
    }

    /* returns a promise that can be utilized using `then() */        
    return response.json();

    // could also use then() here
    // return response.json().then(data => console.log(data));
})
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: what does it mean that with response.json() I get [object Promise]? How to convert it to text?

Comment: To extract the body, which is a readable stream, there are [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods) such as `json()` and `text()` that need to be executed against the `response`. These methods returns promises, which would need to use `then()` to access the inner contents. At the most basic level `response.json().then(data => console.log(data));`. You will not be able to directly access the contents of the body in the first `then()` after fetch. You need to execute one of the these methods and use an additional `then()`. Thanks!